# Batch file to search for FTP users in a FTP log file and copy them to another file

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

Good Day All.

I have a bunch of FTP logs. Now I want to find out which users are using FTP for a given time range. Now I copied the bunch of log files for that time range into a folder, so I want to have a batch script doing the following: Go trough all the log files, in the folder, and search for the following term, which are unique to all the users listed in the log file:

```
USER stblma 331
```

where **stblma** is the user. So 'USER' and '331' will be standard for all logins on the log, but filtering on USER alone will be OK

So now the script must copy the username to a new temp file in the same folder, eg. users.txt

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take as an example this log file

**logs\access-log.log**

```
USER jmacro
331 Password required for jmacro
PASS
230-Checking disk usage, please wait.
230-
230- Your disk quota is: 5.00 megabytes.
230- Your disk usage is:
230- Home/WWW: 1.23 megabytes
230- FTP: 0.00 megabytes
230- Total: 1.23 megabytes (25% of quota)
230-
230 User jmacro@macromedia.com logged in.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8 Version: BSD-198911
PWD
257 "/jmacro" is current directory.
USER nano
331 Password required for jmacro
PASS
230-Checking disk usage, please wait.
230-
230- Your disk quota is: 5.00 megabytes.
230- Your disk usage is:
230- Home/WWW: 1.23 megabytes
230- FTP: 0.00 megabytes
230- Total: 1.23 megabytes (25% of quota)
230-
230 User nano@macromedia.com logged in.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8 Version: BSD-198911
PWD
257 "/nano" is current directory.
```

And this should filter the user names:

**EDIT**

**Now the script removes duplicates**

**filter.bat**

```
@echo off
:: Filter user names
for %%f in (logs\*.log) do (
 type "%%f" | find "USER" >> _temp.txt
)
if exist _temp.txt goto getUser
echo/No users or logs found&pause>nul&exit
:getUser
if not exist users.txt cd 1>nul 2>users.txt
for /f "tokens=2" %%u in ('type _temp.txt') do (
 call:makefile %%u
)
del _temp.txt&exit
:makefile
type users.txt | find /i "%~1" >nul && goto already
echo/%~1 >> users.txt
:already
exit/b
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael. Great script. One thing - The logs repeat usernames, since they are different logs taken from different days. Any way to remove the duplicates in the users.txt file?

Comment: @DextrousDave, now script can remove duplicates

Comment: Thank you very much Rafael, this works like a charm. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /r "USER.*331" *.log') do echo %%a>>users.txt
```

Comment: thank you Matt, it works. But as I ask all the others, how would you remove the duplicate usernames in the users.txt file, since the log files span over different days, so users show up in different logs, hence they will be copied from every log file...

Answer (score 1):

This is a version that will remove the duplicated users and leave one instance of each user:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr "USER" *.log') do echo %%b) >temp.tmp
sort <temp.tmp|uniq >users.txt
del temp.tmp
```

Save this as `uniq.bat` and put it in the same folder as the batch file or in a directory on the path:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" & goto :EOF & Rem aacini 2013

@end

var line, prevLine = "";
while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   if ( line != prevLine ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
      prevLine = line;
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome foxidrive, thank you. Is there a way we can make this script more intelligent - Currently usernames repeat all over the users.txt file, since the users repeat throughout the logs since the logs are drawn from different days...anyway we can remove all duplicate usernames?

Comment: Thank you foxidrive, but it does not work. created the uniq file and updated the code in my original bat file, but still creates duplicates in users.txt

Comment: Did you use the top code in my answer or the amended code in the middle?

Comment: Still does not work. Still creates duplicates. How does your log files look like? Rafael's answer above works now...I just changed "tokens=2" to "tokens=8", since in my log files the string USER is the 8th token

Comment: Your question shows that USER is the start of the line.  I used the log file in Rafael's answer with **logs\access-log.log** in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - ADDED the redirection to final file

EDITED 2 - At last, duplicates removed. There were not enough log files to catch it.

@echo off

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "user="
(for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (
    'find "USER" "*.log" ^| findstr /r "^USER" ^| sort'
) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not "%%a"=="!user!" echo(%%a
    endlocal
    set "user=%%a"
)) > "users.txt"
endlocal
```

Comment: @KevinPanko, Following the line in the rest of the answers, but to complete requirementes, search `USER` lines in *.log, take the second token in the line (the user name), generate a sorted list with this data, and for each element, if it is different from the previous, echo the username. (and thanks for the edit)

Comment: Thanks, but do not get this to work. Did you test this?

Comment: @DextrousDave, yes, i tested it. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: @DextrousDave, re reading the original post, i've seen now the indication to generate an output file. Included in answer. Is this what was not working?

Comment: It creates a blank file at the moment. Is your bat file in the same folder as the log files?

Comment: OK cool - It works now, after removing the ^ before the USER. But it still creates duplicates...

Comment: @DextrousDave, Yes, tested on the same directory. Change the "*.log" to "c:\where\the\files\are\*.log" if needed.

Comment: @DextrousDave, The ^ before USER is telling findstr to search for the USER string at the beginning of line.

Comment: @DextrousDave, Duplicates removed. My problem to detect it was that in my test directory there was only one log file matching the search. One more thing learned. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the update but still creates a blank file. I have about 10 log files in the same folder as the bat file, but does not work...